# Is there a general theorem relating the Dedekind eta function to polynomial roots?

Tags: polynomials, roots, radicals, modular-forms, dedekind-eta-function

This question [The radical solution of a solvable 17th degree equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/65346/1049002)

and these wikipedia pages:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_number#Number_theory

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#Other_characterizations

use the Dedekind eta function to express roots of a polynomial. Is there a theorem or a (specific) field of mathematics where one can learn how to express roots in terms of Dedekind eta functions and which roots are expressible in this manner ?

Comment: Maybe look up Hilbert’s Twelfth Problem, and in particular the imaginary quadratic case, related to class field theory?

Comment: The specific field of mathematics is "Elliptic curves with complex multiplication, class field theory"

Comment: Thank you both I checked a bit of the first reference "Hilbert’s Twelfth Problem" and this does some seem related. I will try to read some more later.